# Search for a name in a column of MySQL and return all its related attributes (one-to-many) in other columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a search box in a php form.

```
<form id="foodForm" action="" method="POST">
    <div id="scrollable-dropdown-menu">
        <input class="typeahead" type="text" name="search" </div> 
        <input type="button" value="ADD" name="add" onclick="functionAdd(); reset();" />
        <input type="button" value="DONE" name="done" onclick="functionDone()" />          
</form>
```

The item searched is for in the first column; **Name** of a mySQL table named **Fnaf** as follows:

Table **Fnaf**

```
----------------------------
| Name    |  A  |  B  |  C |
----------------------------
| Abiyuch |  1  |  2  |  3 |
| Acerola |  4  |  5  |  6 |
| Acorn   |  7  |  8  |  9 |
----------------------------
```

Now, if the user searched for *"Abiyuch"*, I want the search results to be like so:

```
Abiyuch => 1 | 2 | 3
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's a simple SQL. `SELECT A, B, C FROM Fnaf WHERE Name = 'Abiyuch';`

Comment: @executable, can you please explain how can I implement your answer in the context of the searched term? so not an actual word, but rather searched items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialise the database credential. I think this would help you :

```
<form name="form" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search">
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $search = $_POST['search'];

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT A, B, C FROM Fnaf WHERE Name = '$search'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['A'];
            echo $row['B'];
            echo $row['C'];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```